# Escape flash load of Cisco Autonomous AP from Expect script

Tags: scripting, tcl, expect, cisco

I am trying to use a expect script to stop the loading of the flash on a Cisco Autonomous AP so that I can get into the rommon.

```
Loading "flash:/ap3g1-k9w7-mx.124-25d.JA/ap3g1-k9w7-mx.124-25d.JA"...###
```

If you are sitting a keyboard pressing the escape key at this point will stop the process and give you the option to abort and put you to a rommon prompt.

With the expect script I have tried:

- Sending an escape

  ```
  send "\x1B"
  ```

  this is sending the hex value for <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  This is ignored and the process continues.  However this works on a WLC device so I know the value is valid.
- Sending a break

  ```
  send "\x1D"
  expect "telnet>"
  send "send Break\r"
  ```

  this is sending the hex value for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> which is the escape character for but it puts it to `telnet>` prompt. Sending the break comes back from the telnet and continues loading the flash.  On another device that stops the load and puts the device in rommon.

I have also tried the hex for the <kbd>F1</kbd> key and for an arrow key because those work from the keyboard also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `send "\x1B"` will work on an AP as long as the device is set up to allow password recovery.